# Output from Arrays in C won't format?

Tags: c, arrays, formatting

I'm new to this site and was looking for help. I'm trying to design a program that will take an input of numbers from a user, store it into an array, and format them correctly into three columns. However, I can't seem to figure out why my inputs aren't formatting correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int x=0;
float num[100];

/* for loop for receiving inputs from user and storing it in array */
for (x=0; x<=100; x++)
{
    scanf("%f", &num[x]);
    printf("%7.1lf%11.0lf%10.3lf", num[x], num[x+1], num[x+2]);

    //printf("%f %f %f\n", num[0], num[1], num[2]);

}
return 0;
```

Comment: What is your input and your expected output (with correct formatting)?

Comment: You can use any input, but here is an example of how it is coming out.
https://gyazo.com/f0f69ad566794e32c79fa91f8f06efe6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I see:

1. Use of incorrect range in the `for` loop. Given

   ```
   float num[100];
   ```

   the maximum valid index is `99`. Hence, the `for` loop needs to be:

   ```
   for (x=0; x < 100; x++)  // x < 100 not x <= 100
   ```
2. Using array elements before they are initialized.

   ```
   printf("%7.1lf%11.0lf%10.3lf", num[x], num[x+1], num[x+2]);
   ```

   Nothing has been read into `num[x+1]` and `num[x+2]`. Hence, you are going to get garbage values.
3. Accessing `num` using out of bounds array indices.

   Accessing `num[x]`, `num[x+1]`, and `num[x+2]` makes sense only if `x+2` is less than or equal to `97`.

---

My suggestion:

Use two loops. In the first loop, read the data. In the second loop, write out the data.

```
for (x=0; x < 100; x++)  // Using 100 here.
{
    scanf("%f", &num[x]);
}

for (x=0; x < 98; x++)  // Using 98 here.
{
    printf("%7.1lf%11.0lf%10.3lf", num[x], num[x+1], num[x+2]);
}
```

---

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

Change the print loop to:

```
for (x=0; x < 98; x += 3)  // Increment x by 3
{
    printf("%7.1lf%11.0lf%10.3lf", num[x], num[x+1], num[x+2]);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have one more question.
I am supposed to have it where the input will turn out like this.
Three columns with the periods lining up and having an even space between the columns. Kind of like this: https://gyazo.com/54d92853b4d132a49c07e7fb6be4ec73